# Closing Multiple React Components - one after another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, react-hooks

I read through a lot of "close react component on escape / outside click" threads and am able to close **all** opened react components at once.

But: When 2 popups are opened, i want to first close the one "on top", then the one behind it, not **both at the same time**. Here is a pic of the application:

[Screenshot Application with Popups to close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsP1B.png)

My code for a custom hook to close the components:

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export const useOutsideClick = (ref: any, callback: any, when: boolean) => {
  const savedCallback = useRef(callback);

  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  });

  const handler = (e: any) => {
    // check if target event is within the ref

    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      console.log('Handler handling states!');
      savedCallback.current();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (when) {
      document.addEventListener('click', handler);
      return () => document.removeEventListener('click', handler);
    }
  }, [when]);
};
```

With the `useRef` i am creating a connection to a div that needs to be closed an call the `useOutsideClick()` function.

Any ideas how i can achieve closing one component after another? 
Thanks & Greetings!

EDIT: The thing is, i can also close just a single component. The problem is, that like this, the application doesnt know when i click on some other component, it just notices the click when i click on the space where no component is rendered.

Comment: How do you want to close the popup that is on top?
1 - when clicking away (outside of the bounds)
2 - when clicking away and when clicking on the X?
3 - just when clicking on the X?

Comment: I would like to add all 3 options. When hitting the X, when i click on something that is not in the z-index / not on the very top of the application and when hitting the escape button.

Comment: How about https://material-ui.com/api/click-away-listener/?

Comment: Thanks @Alireza, if I'd find any solution without external libs my boss would appreciate it as i shouldnt be using external stuff so much - but thanks!